# error pdo insert query in bd

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

lo siguiente (agradezco su colaboracion y disculpenme si hablo muchas cosas o incluso el pedazo de codigo es muy largo):

Tenia todo mi sistema respaldado en google drive sin agregar aun la funcionalidad que me esta dando error y aun asi antes de hacer el respaldo me creaba cupones de dcto normalmente bien y por eso respalde el codigo (incluida la BD),no me funciono el codigo nuevo despues del respaldo,entonces baje el backup de nuevo e importe la BD y el codigo que si funcionaba completamente bien,pero inserte un cupon y no lo inserta en la BD sin haber modificado el codigo que antes si funcionaba a la perfeccion,entonces ni idea de lo que sucede,no coje errores ni los muestra con PDO de ninguna forma,ya probe try-catch,conexion bien,depure el codigo,probe unset,revise mil y una veces el codigo,tengo display errors ini_set 1 y toda la cosa,no me funciona de ninguna forma lo que antes si estaba bien y la verdad no se de donde proviene el error,(supongo que segun todas las pruebas que hecho,NO es error de sintaxis,NO es error de logica de programacion,NO es error html ni js..es error de BD),no me funciona xamp (por mas de mil maneras que he intentado asi mismo mas de mil maneras y errores he tenido y no lo he podido correr,uso puerto 5050 en xamp porque ningun otro me funciona y no acostumbraba a usar wamp) entonces trabajo con wamp,no se para que realizo un respaldo de algo que si funciona correctamente para luego respladarlo sin haber tocado el codigo y no funcione y como no es la primer vez que se ocultan los errores que deberia de indicar siendo un error de BD la verdad quedo como loco,no se la verdad que hacer,precisamente hago resplado por si acaso algo me queda mal,poder volver a la ultima vez donde todo funcionaba perfectamente (el ctrl + z o deshacer no funciona siempre o de por vida),la verdad no es la primer vez que pasa que paso dias y dias enteros sin saber dde donde proviene el error habiendolo ya intentado todo,amigos les agradezco su colaboracion y aunque se que el codigo es un poco largo se los paso.

```
    <?php require_once('header.php'); ?>

<?php
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_settings");
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($result as $row){
    $row['ValorDolarUS'];
}

?>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['form1'])) {
    $valid = 1;
    
    if(empty($_POST['coupon_name'])) {
        $valid = 0;
        $error_message .= 'Coupon Name can not be empty<br>';
    }
    
    if(empty($_POST['coupon_start_date'])) {
        $valid = 0;
        $error_message .= 'Coupon Start Date can not be empty<br>';
    }
    
    if(empty($_POST['coupon_expire_date'])) {
        $valid = 0;
        $error_message .= 'Coupon Expire Date can not be empty<br>';
    }
    
    if(empty($_POST['coupon_code'])) {
        $valid = 0;
        $error_message .= 'Coupon Code can not be empty<br>';
    }
    
    if(empty($_POST['coupon_type'])) {
        $valid = 0;
        $error_message .= 'Coupon Type can not be empty<br>';
    }
    
    if(empty($_POST['coupon_discount'])) {
        $valid = 0;
        $error_message .= 'Coupon Discount can not be empty<br>';
    }
    
        // AQUI VALIDAMOS SI EL CUPON ES DE TIPO MONTO FIJO LO CONVERTIMOS A DOLARES Y LO INSERTAMOS 
        // EN DOLARES EN LA VARIABLE $CouponDiscount
        if($_POST['coupon_type'] != 'percent_value' || $_POST['coupon_type'] != 'fix_amount'){
            $valid = 0;
        }elseif($_POST['coupon_type'] == 'fix_amount'){
            $CouponDiscount = ($_POST['coupon_discount'] / $ValorDolarUS);
        }elseif($_POST['coupon_type'] == 'percent_value'){
        // PERO SI EL CUPON ES DE OTRO TIPO DISTINTO A LOS UNICOS VALIDOS ( TIPO % ) NO CONVERTIMOS
        // A DOLARES, SINO QUE SOLO INSERTAMOS EL VALOR DEL (%) ESCRITO
            $CouponDiscount = $_POST['coupon_discount'];
        }
    
    //$formated_start_date = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($_POST['coupon_start_date']));
    //$formated_expire_date = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($_POST['coupon_expire_date']));
    $start_date = $_POST['coupon_start_date'];
    
    $expire_date = $_POST['coupon_expire_date'];
    
    $formated_start_date = strtotime($start_date);
    
    $formated_expire_date = strtotime($expire_date);
    
    $fecha_actual = strtotime(date("d-m-Y", time()));
    
    /* NEW CODE 1 */
    if(empty($formated_start_date)){
        $valid = 0;
        $error_message .= '1-Coupon start date can not be empty<br>';
    }else{
            if($formated_start_date < $fecha_actual){
                $valid = 0;
                $error_message .= '2-Coupon start date can not be less than current date<br>';
            }else{
                $coupon_start_date = $formated_start_date;
            }
    }
    /* NEW CODE 1 */
    
    /* NEW CODE 2 */
    if(empty($formated_expire_date)){
        $valid = 0;
        $error_message .= '3-Coupon expire date can not be empty<br>';
    }else{
            if($formated_expire_date < $formated_start_date){
                $valid = 0;
                $error_message .= '4-Coupon expire date can not be less than start date<br>';
            }else{
                $coupon_expire_date = $formated_expire_date;
            }
    }
    /* NEW CODE 2 */
    
    if($valid == 1) {
        
        $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_settings");
        $statement->execute();
        $result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        foreach ($result as $row){
            $row['ValorDolarUS'];
        }
        
        $ValorDolarUS = $row['ValorDolarUS'];

        $statement = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_coupons(
                                        coupon_name,
                                        coupon_start_date,
                                        coupon_expire_date,
                                        coupon_code,
                                        coupon_type,
                                        coupon_discount,
                                        ValorDolarUS
                                    ) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        $statement->execute(array(
                                        $_POST['coupon_name'],
                                        $coupon_start_date,
                                        $coupon_expire_date,
                                        $_POST['coupon_code'],
                                        $_POST['coupon_type'],
                                        $CouponDiscount,
                                        $ValorDolarUS
                                    ));

        $last_id = $pdo->lastInsertId();
        
        $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_product WHERE p_id=?");
        $statement->execute(array($_POST['product_selected_for_discount']));
        $result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        foreach($result as $row) {
            $selected_product_id = $row['p_id'];
        }

        $statement = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE tbl_product SET id_coupon=? WHERE p_id=?");
        $statement->execute(array($last_id,$selected_product_id));
        
        //unset($last_id);
        
        $success_message = 'Coupon is created successfully and its aplied for selected product.';
        
        $reloadpage = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."#CouponsForm";
        header("Location:$reloadpage");
        exit();
        
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: Capaz algun experto en php te puede ayudar, pero unos tips: para respaldar codigo, usa git. en google no respaldas.. copias.. y obviamente, no puedes volver a versiones anteriores. Para tu DB, haz un backup. o exporta el diseño. yo creo que va a ser muy dificil saber que no funciona, sin poder replicar el error de alguna forma. Decir no funciona, es lo mismo que nada.. Estaras mirando la base correcta? estaras haciendo algo despues de esto que hacen que desaparezcan los datos? si haces un insert a mano funciona? probaste tu codigo paso a paso? Estan pasando muchas cosas ahi....

Comment: exactamente sucede que los servidor en windows xampp, wamp, laragon no se llevan con ningun sistema que guada datos en la nuve (dropbox, googledrive, onedrive) te lo digo por que ya lo sufri y como dijo el moderador diamantado ... yo comence a usar git y git desktop para manejar el control de versiones locales y github para manejarlo en la nuve.

Comment: todo esto pareciera que tu servidor ha dejado de funcionar correctamente ... te recomiendo mover el path de tu servidor a un lugar donde no este bajo la imfuencia de google drive... reinicia el ordenador y prueba. de momento este escenario no lo podemos reproducir para ayudarte hasta que consigas el error que te esta afectanto ... si no te sale por pantall fijate en los logs.

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 hola,acabo de ver la consola en firefox (la verdad es que no la se usar,han aparecido cosas ahi pero que no tienen que ver con el codigo sino solo con el navegador,nunca pense que saliera algo por ahi) pero aparece un mensaje indicandome como que un elemento no puede estar nulo y es en la pagina de cupones de mi tienda en linea donde me sale ese error justo despues de que envio el formulario (y tambien antes de usar form me doy cuenta) sin poder insertar nada,te dejo un link que es una imagen ,porfavor abrelo para que puedas ver https://ibb.co/kSCNQGm

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 pero veo que es un error de javascript que aplica un estilo,parece un arreglo,no se de donde proviene,me sale en la paina de cupones pero en el footer,no afecta codigo php,pdo,sql https://ibb.co/cgnbmrg

Comment: @santiagozuluaga la imagen no se aprecia y no se aprecia el error, en estos casos es aconcejable que copies el error de la consola y lo coloques aqui en el post utilizando la opcion de edicion.

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 Hola,la verdad el error que me daba es de puro codigo js incluso estaba usando conexiones y consultas preparadas con PDO,la unica forma de solucion que encontre fue crear un archibo crear_cupones.php en vez de ejecutar el codigo de crear en la misma pagina pero me toco que usar mysqli normal,con PDO fue imposible,me toco aplicar un monton de formatos a las fechas que ni para que necesidad,en la parte del cupon del dcto en las condicionales convertia de pesos(ingresados en el form) a dolares hacia la BD,solo no cojia el ELSEIF,toco puro IF anidado,es decir poco de cosa sin sentido

Comment: pero PDO es mejor en todo eso no se cual es el problema con las fechas, esto seria otra pregunta